# CSS Dropdown Twitching

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am developing a website, and using a traditional technique of CSS-only dropdown-menu, but integrating CSS3 attributes. That being said, the client wants specific menu items that push the bounds of the

s that contain them. This is causing twitching when transitioning between menus.

The CSS looks like this:

```
#nav{
background-image:url(../images/nav-bg.png);
height: 32px;
width: 100%;
padding-right:8px;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
z-index:3;
}

#drop { list-style-type: none; height: 32px; padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; width: 500px; vertical-align: baseline; color: #fbf9ec; }
#drop li { float: left; position: relative; padding: 0; line-height: 32px; background: #3a7c38 url(../images/nav-bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;}
#drop li:hover { background-position: 0 -40px;}
#drop li a { display: block; padding: 0 15px; color: #fbf9ec; text-decoration: none; }
#drop li a:hover { color: #fbf9ec; }
#drop li ul { opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; width: 14em; background: #3a7c38; list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 2; box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px #888;}
#drop li:hover ul { opacity: 1; }
#drop li ul li { float: none; position: static; height: 0; line-height: 0; background: none; }
#drop li:hover ul li { height: 30px; line-height: 30px; }
#drop li ul li a { background: #3a7c38; }
#drop li ul li a:hover { background: #254F24; }
```

The live example can be found at:

MasonandLauren.com/flotec/secondary.html

(Don't worry - The design is based on customer request, not my own)

Any help to eliminate the twitching would be appreciated!

Thanks!
~Mason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the z-index of your main nav items to `3`  (the sub menu items +1).

It looks like the z-index of the sub tabs was causing them to be sequentially over and under the mouse as it moved.

```
#trans-nav li {
float: left;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
line-height: 32px;
background: #3A7C38 url(../images/nav-bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;
z-index: 3;  /* <-- this is the new one */
```

Comment: Great! I tested it using 3 and 4, which seems to be the right configuration. Thanks!